# Different payment processors for different price fields?

Tags: civicontribute

Is it possible to specify different payment processors for different price fields in a price set on a single contribution page?

I have a contribution page with two prices: £A for EFT, and £B for Direct Debit. £A is more expensive than £B to incentivize Direct Debit.

Direct Debit is chosen by the user selecting the Direct Debit price field, £B, selecting the pay later option, and then the user is directed to the DD form which they fill in and send.

However, a user can select price field £B and then select Credit/Debit Cards, thus paying the cheaper £B price.

I've found the extension 'Direct Debit for Membership Extras' (https://civicrm.org/extensions/direct-debit-for-membership-extras), but after testing with it, it still doesn't solve the issue of a user being able to choose the price field without limiting the choice of payment processor. Is this possible? The only workaround I can think of is to have two separate contribution pages, one for EFT price and one for DD price.

I've found some old posts ([Fee based on payment processor](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9830/fee-based-on-payment-processor), [Adding a dynamic “cover processing fees” checkbox to CiviCRM contribution form](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/62/adding-a-dynamic-cover-processing-fees-checkbox-to-civicrm-contribution-form), and https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=33098.0) but I'm hoping there exists a more recent extension to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution however you can give the user the option for either payment method on the contribution page.

Then utilise JavaScript to automatically react and select the correct payment method.

This is assuming is a small difference and you don't need it to be 100% secure etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

We have an extension that adds on a percent and an option fixed amount to any payment via Credit Card - so in theory this may achieve what you are after but via a different method

https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.extrafee