# Percentage Price Field extension not working for Additional Participants?

Tags: civievent, extension, percentage-price-field

It seems like the Percentage Price Field extension mentioned in post [Adding a dynamic “cover processing fees” checkbox to CiviCRM contribution form](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/62/adding-a-dynamic-cover-processing-fees-checkbox-to-civicrm-contribution-form/15401#15401) is ideal for my needs, except for one problem:  payment type exclusions are not followed in the Additional Participant template, and the percentage is always added to additional participant form totals regardless of the payment type chosen on the first registration page.

How to reproduce:
-- Create an event where one person can register multiple participants at once
-- Configure a percentage price field in a price set to add 3.5%, "Hide checkbox and force to "yes" is checked (to suppress the optional checkbox), and "Disable for payment methods" is selected for "Pay Later".
-- Go to the event registration page and say you are registering 2 people.
-- the first registration page works fine; the user is given a payment option choice, and the percentage is added only if they choose a payment processor, not for Pay Later
-- Click continue to load the additional participant form.  The total always adds 3.5 percent regardless of the choice made on the first form.

Is there a way for the payment method choice made on the first form to persist to the additional participant registration forms?

Appreciate help from anyone who's had experience with this extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard back from the developer directly on GitHub who said this feature might be included in the future.