# Add transaction fee

Tags: payment-processor, payment, eway

How do we take transaction fees into account when setting up a price on Civi?

We have prices for what we charge for memberships and training, but how do we set a percentage for transaction fee for our various price sets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a dynamic “cover processing fees” checkbox to CiviCRM contribution form](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/62/adding-a-dynamic-cover-processing-fees-checkbox-to-civicrm-contribution-form)

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked out https://civicrm.org/extensions/percentage-price-field ?
Great extension

Answer (score 2):

If you’re on Drupal you can use Webform CiviCRM module and Webform Calculator module -> to calculate transaction fees based on other fields, authorization fee and percentage -> If you go this route let me know and I’ll post an updated link to a version of Webform Calculator module code with some fixes.